# flink sql with Couldn't retrieve Yarn cluster

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

when I run "sql-client.sh -f flinkSQL.sql"
I get a error "java.lang.RuntimeException: The Yarn application application_1675126034346_0011 doesn't run anymore."

in log

```
2023-03-27 15:51:46,649 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2023-03-27 15:51:46,932 ERROR org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - The application application_1675126034346_0011 doesn't run anymore. It has previously completed with final status: SUCCEEDED
2023-03-27 15:51:47,034 WARN  org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient                  [] - Could not execute SQL statement.
org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Could not execute SQL statement.
........
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
........
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterRetrieveException: Couldn't retrieve Yarn cluster
.......
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Yarn application application_1675126034346_0011 doesn't run anymore.
```

but I can run other jar like
"bin/flink run-application -t yarn-application /hadoop/app/flinksqltest.jar"

so why ?

Comment: Did you configure a `yarn-site.xml` file? Is there a YARN ResourceManager available for you to use?

Comment: what do I need configure in yarn-site.xml.  I can run jar , I can run spark, only can't run sql-client.sh

Comment: The Flink docs cover how to start/use YARN https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/deployment/resource-providers/yarn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a error Hadoop config path
CDH config is /etc/hadoop/conf